# ImportError: cannot import name urandom Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I know this question has been asked many times, but I couldn't manage to solve it on my own. So please bear with me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/someone/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 3, in <module>
        import pydev_imports
      File "/Users/someone/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818/pysrc/pydev_imports.py", line 14, in <module>
        from _pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
      File "/Users/someone/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818/pysrc/_pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 116, in <module>
        import BaseHTTPServer
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 81, in <module>
        import mimetools
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
        import tempfile
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
        from random import Random as _Random
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
        from os import urandom as _urandom
    ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

echo $PATH gave me this. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

My goal is to setup an IDE that gives me code completion and breakpoint debug(like java, so that I can debug it line by line). I've read many posts here, but still haven't find a solution to it.  Can anyone point to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I upgraded python to 2.7.3 because i couldn't select the interpreter in eclipse preferences.

Comment: Hi, I seem to be having the same problem that you had in this question. I tried following the instructions in the link in the answer below, but I'm still getting the same result. Please take a look at my question if you think you can help. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981094/running-python-locally-in-aptana-studio-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html). All you need to do is make a proper configuration of your interpreter.
If it doesn't help, you should take a look at [another one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bug/989856) (the second one is about `urandom` module, whilst the first one about `pydev` configuration).